# Why do I need to Bitwise AND with 1 the shift righted char in binary to get the correct binary value?

Tags: c, while-loop, bit-manipulation, unsigned-char, bitwise-and

This is the exercise that I'm doing:

## Assignment name  : print_bits

### Expected files   : print_bits.c
Allowed functions: write

Write a function that takes a byte, and prints it in binary WITHOUT A NEWLINE
AT THE END.
Your function must be declared as follows:

void    print_bits(unsigned char octet);

Example, if you pass 2 to print_bits, it will print "00000010"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

This is a solution:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void    print_bits(unsigned char octet)
{
        int             i;
        unsigned char   bits;

        i = 8;
        while (i--)
        {
                bits = (octet >> i & 1) + '0';
                write(1, &bits, 1);
        }
}
```

I understand the solution, except for one part. If I right shift the char in its binary form, why do I need to perform a Bitwise AND with 1?? What would be the difference? I supposedly should get the same solution, since I'm performing the operation always with the 1 at the final bit of 1. If the bit from the unsigned char is 0, I'll get 0. If it's 1, I'll get 1. But if I try to run the program with an example without the Bitwise AND operation, I get way beyond 0 and 1. Why?

Comment: If you shift 128 right 1, is the value just 0 or 1?  What happens if you add it to '0'?  You are only looking at the value of the lowest bit not all of the others left in the number

Comment: Because you want to zero out all the bits except the LSB in order to print it bitwise.

Comment: That is, if your `octet` is `5`, for example, then `octet >> 1` will be `2`. So you will be printing `2` instead of the expected LSB of `2`, which is `0`.

Comment: @DaveS Now I understand perfectly what you mean :) Too much string manipulation made me look at it like I was looking at an array. But now I get that the written value is the char corresponding to the full bit in bits after all the job is done. Thanks Dave :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I get 100% now. Nicely explained Eugene :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right-shift operation, denoted with `>>`, does not just take one bit from the left operand and shift it. It shifts all the bits of the left operand. For example, given **1101**1001<sub>2</sub> shifted right four bits, the result is **1101**<sub>2</sub>. If you do not AND that with 1, the result is 13 (1101<sub>2</sub>). If you do AND it with 1, the result is 1.

In C implementations using ASCII, the character “0” has code 48, and, if you add 13 to `'0'`, you will get 61, the code for “=”.

Comment: Couldn't be better explained. Thank you Eric! :)

Answer (score 2):

`(octet >> i & 1)` can be split into two operations

1. `octet >> i` is bringing the bit of your interest into lowest position.
2. `& 1` is taking the value of the lowest position bit only. It zeroes all other bits so the result can be `0` or `1`. You can also use "modulo" operation (`% 2`) instead

Comment: % 2 as they are binaries :) Got it!